# Android app not posting to google sheet

Tags: android, google-sheets, app-inventor

I have got an android app that I would like the barcode scanning page to post to a google sheet but I keep getting the following error message:

[image]

and my coding blocks like this. I don't understand why it does not work because I have implemented these code blocks on another page of the app to post to google sheets and that works perfectly fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the `PostText` block instead of the `PostFile` block...
   [see also my tutorial](https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php)
2. the `Textbox1.GotFocus` event does not make sense like this, you can remove it completely
3. if there is only one `Textbox` to check, what about removing the second `is empty? Textbox1.Text` block...

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works great. So say if I wanted to call my google spreadsheet columns including this one, on a different screen in the form of a table separating as they are in the google spreadsheet how would I be able to do that.

Comment: you could download the complete table and display it using [this solution](https://puravidaapps.com/table.php)... btw. do you already know [how to accept an answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: However if I download the complete table I will have a problem because the google sheet will be continuously updating will the new data also come through each time viewing the table.

Comment: You will have to continuously download the data to be able to display the updates then. Alternatively you might want to take a look into working with fusiontables, see also the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty)

Comment: I have tried using the download example but after it gets to a 100% it show a pop up saying Runtime Error giving the option to end application and also a notifier saying running. However whenever i check in the Downloads folder it has downloaded images and videos which is not my spreadsheet. I have given the direct download link to my spreadsheet as well

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you are taking about, you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)